# Uncaught Error: Syntax error WordPress - Unable to Post Comments

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm unable to post comments on my site, I've tried using the standard comments system and de:comments.

**When using the standard comments system it takes me to a blank white page with:**

*You're spam! aren't you?*

Written at the top (I've tried on several devices and on mobile, different IP etc).

**De:comments shows this error in the console:**

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: You're spam! aren't you?*

See image below for full error:

[image: unable to post comments]

I've been looking at this for the past week and so far haven't found a solution. It is an adult site so won't post the link - I'm just hoping I've given enough information for someone to be able to help?

Comment: Can you search your codebase for the string "You're spam! aren't you?"?

Comment: This is not a PHP error. My best guess would be a csrf token not being posted with the form data.